# How to prevent iframe from opening in a new tab

Tags: javascript

I have a iframe, in that iframe, there is links inside the website that if you click it, it opens in a new tab. How do I disable the "open in a new tab", and make it to just open in the same iframe? I have looked all around Stack Overflow, and there are no answers that actaully work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have very little control on what the browser does. its not your machine...

Comment: if it opens in a new tab, that's because the `A` tag as a `target` value of `_blank` ; don't think you can override that, if the iframe is not part of your website

Comment: @Pierre what would you mean by it is "not part of your website, don't worry, i just dont understand :) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the code inside the iframe website, you would need to set the `href` tags to have target properties of `_self`. Like the following:

```
  <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" target="_self">stackoverflow</a>
```

If you cannot change to code of the iframe website, you could still run a javascript or jQuery script to add that property **if the iframe website is loaded from the same domain as your website.**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var $iframe = $("iframe");
    $('#frame').on('load', function() {
       $(this).contents().find("a").attr('target', '_self');
    });
});
```

This will find hyperlinks and set the target attribute to `_self` which instructs the browser to open the link in the same window.

If your website is from domain A (eg. mysite.com) and the iframe is from domain B (eg. othersite.com), web browser security prevents javascript to manipulate the iframe content.

Comment: Thank you so much, I guess I'll find another solution.